# document.querySelectorAll attribute value with carriage return

Tags: javascript, html

I have a (assumed) poorly constructed HTML document and I'm trying to select a particular button, but the value of the attribute contains a carriage return.  Using Chrome, I can right click and copy the element HTML and paste into Notepad++ and then show special characters and the [CR][LF] is there.

I've tried this with no success:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button[title='Attribute<br>Value']')[0].click();
```

I've tried this with no success:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button[title='Attribute\nValue']')[0].click();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, line breaks are valid in attributes; this isn’t poorly constructed. Use ``document.querySelectorAll(`button[title=${CSS.escape("Attribute\nValue")}]`)``. `CSS.escape("Attribute\nValue")` returns `"Attribute\\a Value"`, which you can also use directly.

Comment: As a sidenote, `'button[title='Attribute<br>Value']'` and `'button[title='Attribute\nValue']'` are syntactically wrong and would raise an error (something like *"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"*).

Comment: @ths The _selector_ is invalid, but the JavaScript syntax itself is fine.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it will be considered as a syntax error and the `querySelectorAll` method won't even execute. On Chrome, the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` will be thrown.

Comment: @ths Oh, I missed the wrong quotes; you’re right: `document.querySelectorAll('button[title='Attribute\nValue']')[0].click();` isn’t even valid in terms of basic JS syntax. `document.querySelectorAll("button[title='Attribute\nValue']")[0].click();` would get the JS syntax right, but fail the CSS syntax.

Comment: Thank you both.  Not sure why my searches were turning up nothing with that other already answered question.